# converting character or integer to md5 hash using python script

Tags: python, sql, md5

I used SQL to convert a social security number to MD5 hash.  I am wondering if there is a module or function in python/pandas that can do the same thing.

My sql script is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MD5HASH(STR IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  V_CHECKSUM VARCHAR2(32);

BEGIN
  V_CHECKSUM := LOWER(RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(SYS.DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT_ST    RING => STR))));
  RETURN V_CHECKSUM;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END MD5HASH;

SELECT HRPRO.MD5HASH('555555555') FROM DUAL
```

thanks.

I apologize, now that I read back over my initial question it is quite confusing.

I have a data frame that contains the following headings:

```
df[['ssno','regions','occ_ser','ethnicity','veteran','age','age_category']][:10]
```

Where ssno is personal information that I would like to convert to an md5 hash number and then create a new column into the dataframe.

thanks... sorry for the confusion.

Right now I have to send my file to Oracle and then convert the ssn to hash and then export back out so that I can continue working with it in Pandas.  I want to eliminate this step.

Comment: Have you tried googling `python md5`? Second result for me is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Isn't this simply `hashlib.md5(ssn).hexdigest()`? Though sha256 would be a better choice.

Comment: @timkofu: I _think_ david wants to use MD5 to be compatible with his existing SQL code. But I could be totally wrong. :) In which case, SHA256 would be a better choice if he needs the extra security it affords.

Comment: @timkofu:  thank you for the response.  I do not want to use the SQL code.  It is an extra step in my process that I would like to eliminate.

Comment: @david: select correct answer if your issue resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard hashlib module:

```
import hashlib

hash = hashlib.md5()
hash.update('555555555')
print hash.hexdigest()
```

**output**

```
3665a76e271ada5a75368b99f774e404
```

As mentioned in timkofu's comment, you can also do this more simply, using

```
print hashlib.md5('555555555').hexdigest()
```

The `.update()` method is useful when you want to generate a checksum in stages. Please see the [hashlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) (or the [Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

hashlib with `md5` might be of your interest.

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").hexdigest()
```

output:

```
bb649c83dd1ea5c9d9dec9a18df0ffe9
```

Constructors for hash algorithms that are always present in this module are `md5(), sha1(), sha224(), sha256(), sha384(), and sha512()`.

If you want more condensed result, then you may try `sha` series

output for `sha224`:

```
'a4337bc45a8fc544c03f52dc550cd6e1e87021bc896588bd79e901e2'
```

For more details : [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)

Comment: My point is: He explicitly asked for the solution for a `md5` hash. Your answer is a little bit confusing because for some reason you focus on `sha224`.